# How can I have equal distance between tick marks on x axis in a matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram from a list of float numbers. Due to the distribution of the floats I use customized bin and log scale to make the graph look better. But the distance between tick marks on x axis is not consistent so every bin is of different width, as is shown in the image below. Like the distance between `1e+6` and  `1e+22` is much longer and that bin is much wider than the others.

Here's my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x_values = [1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 2e+2, 1.2e+3, 7e+3, 1e+5, 1e+6, 1e+22]

plt.figure(figsize=(25,6))

plt.hist(float_l, bins=x_values)

# Set the x-axis scale to logarithmic
plt.xscale('log')

# Set the x-axis labels
plt.xticks(x_values, x_values)

plt.title('Float Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Float')
plt.ylabel('Count')

plt.show()
```

The histogram I get from it:
[image]

How can I have equal distance between tick marks?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `np.logspace` to get evenly spaced log scale numbers for distanced between `xticks`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_values = [1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 2e+2, 1.2e+3, 7e+3, 1e+5, 1e+6, 1e+22]
float_l = np.logspace(1,22,len(x_values)) #dummy float_l, replace by your own value
x_ticks = np.logspace(1,22,len(x_values))
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

plt.hist(float_l, bins=x_values)

# Set the x-axis scale to logarithmic
plt.xscale('log')
# Set the x-axis labels
plt.xticks(x_ticks,x_values)

plt.title('Float Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Float')
plt.ylabel('Count')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The solution you provide make distances between tick marks equal, but doesn't make every bin have same width and the bin is not aligned with tick mark, the histogram looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fKtg.png